# Splitting strings then pasting them randomly together

Tags: r, string, vector

I have two vectors:

```
presidents = c("Bill Clinton", "George Bush", "Ronald Reagan", "Jimmy Carter", "Gerald Ford")

vice.presidents = vice.presidents = c("Al Gore", "Dan Quayle", "George Bush","Walter Mondale", "Nelson Rockefeller")
```

I am trying to get a results using `substr()` of the form `"Clinton+Quayle",  "Bush+..."` with just last names and where a randomly selected president is paired with a randomly selected vice president.

Comment: Could do `paste(sample(sub(".* ", "", presidents)), sample(sub(".* ", "", vice.presidents)))` or such. Though you could get "Bush" twice as he present in both strings.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Better than my answer, post it as an answer and you'll get an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
set.seed(1843)
p <- sapply(strsplit(presidents, " "), '[', 2)
vp <- sapply(strsplit(vice.presidents, " "), '[', 2)
n <- 5
paste(sample(p, n, TRUE), sample(vp, n, TRUE))
```

First, split the names by white-space and keep only the 2nd part, the last name.
Then, sample at random from the result vectors and paste them together.

Answer (score 0):

### A solution with `stringr` package using regular expression

```r
presidents = c("Bill Clinton", "George Bush", "Ronald Reagan", "Jimmy Carter", "Gerald Ford")

vice.presidents = c("Al Gore", "Dan Quayle", "George Bush","Walter Mondale", "Nelson Rockefeller")

library(stringr)
str_c(sample(str_extract(presidents, pattern = "\\b[[:alpha:]]*\\b$")), 
      sample(str_extract(vice.presidents, pattern = "\\b[[:alpha:]]*\\b$")),
      sep = "+")
#> [1] "Bush+Bush"        "Reagan+Mondale"   "Ford+Rockefeller"
#> [4] "Carter+Gore"      "Clinton+Quayle"
```

#### About the regex

- `\\b` is a delimeter for a word boundary
- `[[:alpha:]]` is one letter from A to z
- `*` is match the previous character zero or more time
- `$` delimits the end of the character chain
- Then `\\b[:alpha:]\\b$` match the last word, here it is the last name

### A solution using fonctional programming with `purrr` from the `tidyverse`

It is just a rewrite of the previous answer using a pipe syntax

```r
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
list(presidents, vice.presidents) %>% 
  map(sample) %>%
  map(str_extract, pattern = "\\b[[:alpha:]]+\\b$") %>%
  invoke(str_c, ., sep = "+")
#> [1] "Reagan+Quayle"    "Clinton+Bush"     "Carter+Mondale"  
#> [4] "Ford+Gore"        "Bush+Rockefeller"
```